# Controlling variance manually for a latent factor w/ only one manifest indicator using lavaan in R

Tags: r, panel-data, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor, lavaan

Using lavaan in R, I'm trying to reproduce a CFA/SEM model from a publication (cf. Figure 1 of https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/desc.12202).

[image: Figure 1]

Below is the correlation table and std. dev. vector from the publication. I know the numbers are correct because I can reproduce the model in Figure 2 perfectly (getting the same output and structure).

```
library(lavaan)
library(semPlot)
data.cor = lav_matrix_lower2full(c(1.00,
                        .306, 1.0,
                        .334, .368, 1.0,
                        .479, .207, .266, 1.0,
                        .338, .518, .288, .274, 1.0,
                        .333, .306, .371, .314, .409, 1.0,
                        .337, .164, .294, .529, .291, .326, 1.0,
                        .196, .449, .311, .240, .576, .324, .248, 1.0,
                        .320, .267, .363, .173, .337, .560, .298, .404, 1.0))

rownames(data.cor) = 
  colnames(data.cor) = c("SRT1","BPVST1","GCT1","SRT2","BPVST2","GCT2","SRT3","BPVST3","GCT3")

sd.cor = c(1.91, 11.11, 3.79, 2.11, 11.26, 3.7, 2.06, 11.79, 3.75)

data.cov = cor2cov(data.cor, sd.cor)
```

Now the model in Figure 1 is described as a "bivariate simplex model." Where I seem to be getting hung up is how to implement the following step from the paper:

> *In this model the error variance for the sentence repetition latent variable was fixed to be equal to the observed error variance on the task at each time point (based on Cronbach’s alpha for the sample).*

Here is the table depicting Cronbach's alpha:

[image: Table]

In my code (below) the latent variable in question is called WM1/WM2/WM3.

```
model_a = "
WMT1 =~ a*SRT1
WMT2 =~ a*SRT2
WMT3 =~ a*SRT3
WMT3~WMT2
WMT2~WMT1
LANGT1 =~ b*BPVST1+c*GCT1
LANGT2 =~ b*BPVST2+c*GCT2
LANGT3 =~ b*BPVST3+c*GCT3
LANGT2 ~ LANGT1
LANGT3 ~ LANGT2
LANGT1~~WMT1
LANGT2~WMT1
WMT2~LANGT1
LANGT3~WMT2
WMT3~LANGT2
BPVST1~~BPVST2
BPVST2~~BPVST3
BPVST1~~BPVST3
GCT2~~GCT3
"

model_a.fit = cfa(model_a,
            sample.cov=data.cov,
            sample.nobs=216,
            orthogonal=F)

semPaths(model_a.fit,whatLabels="std",layout="spring")

summary(model_a.fit, 
        fit.measure=TRUE, 
        rsquare=TRUE, 
        standardized=TRUE)
```

The authors specify that the unstandardized factor loadings between the measures and the latent variables are constrained to be equal over time, hence the way I've set them up in my code.

The image generated by semPaths shows that I am at least generating the proper model structure with this code. Where I'm lost is how to get errors for the observed variables SR1/SR2/SR3 that are not equal to 0.0 and how to actually get loadings that are not indexed to 1.0.

It's tricky because this latent factor (WM1/WM2/WM3 in my code, and "Sentence Repetition" in the publication) only has one observed/manifest variable at each of its three time points (SR1/SR2/SR3).

Thanks in advance for help with a tricky problem.

Comment: The paper is not clear enough. There are additional constraints in their model that they are not describing (calculate the degrees of freedom yourself - they don't match).

Comment: @JeremyMiles Thank you so much for looking into it! Any thoughts on how they might have gotten a real factor loading out of a single-indicator setup for the top layer of latent variables like that?

Comment: @JeremyMiles Could the mismatch in degrees of freedom simply be because they are fixing the three parameters for the sentence repetition latent variable (the variance) instead of estimating them?

Comment: Not sure. They have 9 variables, so 45 moments. I count 34 parameters, so they should have 11 df. They say there are 19 df, so there are 8 additional constraints. Fixing the variances gives you only three.